# Erro ao enviar email através da função mail

Tags: php, html, envio-de-email

Eu preciso de fazer um **form** que envie para um mail a mensagem. Eu já utilizei o "mailto:....." mas quando fui testar estava sempre a abrir o outlook.

Então foi pesquisar e acabei com este código em [**PHP**](http://ul.to/l9erxig2).

```
<?php 

if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "erro!";
}

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

if(empty($nome)||empty($mail)){
    echo "Nome e mail obrigatórios";
    exit;
}

$mail2 = "bbgibellino@gmail.com";
$assunto = "Saber Infinito";
$corpo = "Recebeu uma mensagem de $nome.\n E-mail: $mail.\n 
Telefone: $telefone.\n Mensagem:\n $mensagem";

$para = "bbgibellino@gmail";
$header = "E-mail de $nome";

$result = mail($para,$assunto,$corpo,$header);

if(!$result) {   
     echo "<script>
        document.location.href = '../index.html';   
        alert('Erro! Mensagem não enviada!');    
     </script>"; 
} else {
    echo "<script>
        document.location.href = '../index.html';   
        alert('Obrigado! Mensagem enviada');
     </script>";
}

?>
```

PS: Desculpem mandar através de um site mas não consegui incorporar na pergunta

Comment: Bruno embora a pergunta não seja duplicata, a resposta é a certa para a sua pergunta. Se achar que as respostas dessa pergunta não o ajudam refira aqui o porquê.

Comment: @JorgeB. Mas eu não quero enviar anexos e essa pergunta e focada nesse ponto. Não sei se viu o anexo que enviei, mas aquilo que está no link que postou já tenho, o problema é que não funciona. E eu gostava de saber o porquê.

Comment: Então tem de por o código que você tem e como o está a usar para termos uma ideia de qual será o problema.

Comment: E o log do PHP quanto tenta enviar o mail.

Comment: Faz  `var_dump($result);` e comenta o código do if - else...

Comment: Aconselho você a usar o PHPMailer, pois tem várias funcionalidades, principalmente enviar e-mails autenticados. Veja o tutorial do colega Thiago Belem. http://blog.thiagobelem.net/enviar-e-mails-pelo-php-usando-o-phpmailer/